# how to initialize and display a new button after mouse click on another button

Tags: java, swing

I want to display a new button on screen after another button (named `done`) is clicked.

I have to get a `gridSize` from text field by user. After user clicks on `done` button, I have to initialize `JButtons` array of size `[gridSize][gridSize]`.

For now, I have initialized a new `JButton` as `gridCell` in the mouse action listener of `done` button. But `gridCell` button does not appear when I click on `done` button.  Where as it does appear when I initialize the `gridCell` button outside the scope of `Mouse listener` of `done` button.

Here's the code that shows initialization of `gridCell` inside action listener of `done` button.

```
    JButton btnDone = new JButton("Done");
    btnDone.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

            int gridSize = Integer.parseInt(textArea.getText());
            textArea.setText(""+gridSize);
            gridCell = new JButton[gridSize][gridSize];
            gridCell[0][0].setBounds(90, 140, 27, 23);
            frame.getContentPane().add(gridCell[0][0]);

        }
    });
    btnDone.setBounds(393, 12, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnDone);
```

Comment: Don't add/remove controls in that way, the controls are controlled by the manager and thus should be initialized after they are created.

Comment: But I have to initialize an array of a particular `gridsize` and that size is known only after mouse click is performed.

Comment: Could you add all necessary code? It's hard to tell exactly what is done when all code is not included. From what I can see now, you're not changing the layout at all, so maybe create a  separate area that you add a GridLayout to, with the size that the user gives it.

Comment: 1) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 3) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE].